# Using Array.prototype.every or Array.property.some depending on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a function to filter some data using OR/AND logical operator depending on what the user selects.
That means I need to use Array.prototype.every (AND) or Array.property,some (OR) to fullfill my requirement.

To avoid code redundancy I was trying to do something like this:

```
const functionApplied = condition === 'ALL'
        ? myArray.every
        : myArray.some;

functionApplied(item =>  {
    ... aux code ...
})
functionApplied.call(item =>  {
    ... aux code ...
})
```

Is there an analogous way to do it like this?

I know I could do something like this, but I'm just curious about above sintax...

```
const auxFunction = (item) => {...};
if (condition === 'ALL') {
    myArray.every(item => auxFunction(item));
} else {
    myArray.some(item => auxFunction(item));
}
```

Comment: *"I was trying to do something like this"*: please explain which problem you encountered with that approach.

Comment: The proper `.call` usage is `functionApplied.call(myArray, item =>  { ... aux code ... })` since you need to supply the value for `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do something similar to what you're hoping to achieve. Here's one way:

```js
function checkCondition(condition, booleanFunc, myArray) {
    const functionApplied = condition === 'ALL'
        ? myArray.every.bind(myArray)
        : myArray.some.bind(myArray);

    return functionApplied(booleanFunc);
}

console.log(checkCondition('ANY', (item) => {return item > 2}, [1,4,5,6]));
console.log(checkCondition('ANY', (item) => {return item > 2}, [4,5,6]));
console.log(checkCondition('ANY', (item) => {return item > 2}, [1,2]));
console.log(checkCondition('ALL', (item) => {return item > 2}, [1,4,5,6]));
console.log(checkCondition('ALL', (item) => {return item > 2}, [4,5,6]));
```

VLAZ comment is another good direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, VLAZ comment is the way I wanted, this works:

```
const functionApplied = condition === 'ALL'
        ? Array.prototype.every
        : Array.prototype.some;

functionApplied.call(myArray, item =>  {
    ... aux code
```

Thanks everyone for your quick answers :)

Answer (score 0):

const result = (myArray[condition === 'ALL' ? 'every': 'some'])(item => auxFunction(item))

this is minimal one line answer you can find

feel free to to seprate condition and min looping function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the following:

```js
const fn = condition === 'ALL' ? "every" : "some";
const result = myArray[fn]((item) => {
  // ... aux code ...
});
```

Storing the function name `every` or `some` in a variable called `fn`. Then calling it supplying your aux code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable holding the property name, and then use dynamic property access.

```js
function functionApplied(condition) {
  return functionApplied === 'ALL' ? 'every' : 'some';
}

let result = myArray[functionApplied(condition)](item => { ... });
```